# Visual Studio 2012 thinks I'm on Windows 8 and demands libraries I don't have?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, directx-11, xaudio2

I implemented the code from one of the samples in the DirectX 11 SDK from June 2010.I open my project in 2012 and then I open the sample in 2012 too,however when I run mine,it requires XAudio2_8.dll.How is thsi even possible?That's the .dll in Windows 8 and the code from the SDK is from 2010 - such .dll didn't exist back then?The weirdest thing is the SDK sample builds and runs,while my project asks for the .dll.I linked all the libs,made all the includes,I checked around the project settings,searched the whole hard drive for such a dll,nothing...What could be causing such a problem?I've also been having all sorts of other problems in the SDK under VS2012,like not recognizing types in the dx11 headers and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows 8.x SDK has the DirectX SDK integrated into it, which for many areas means you don't need to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all. In particular, Direct3D, DirectSound, DirectInput, etc. all have the proper headers and libs in the Windows 8.x SDK.

The DirectX SDK is quite venerable, so there are a number of older things missing: no DirectMusic playback, DirectPlay, etc. I have a [blog](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/) post that provides a full inventory of what happened to everything in the DirectX SDK.

Where it gets complicated is XAudio and XInput. Both XAudio 2.8 and XInput 1.4 are part of the Windows 8.x OS, but is not available on Windows 7. If you are targeting 'down-level' to Windows 7, you have to use XAudio 2.7 and either XInput 1.3 or XInput 9.1.0. This somewhat messy story is covered in two blog entries: one for [XInput](https://walbourn.github.io/xinput-and-windows-8/) and one for [XAudio](https://walbourn.github.io/xaudio2-and-windows-8/). The good news is that most use of XInput is actually doable with XInput 9.1.0 which is part of the Windows OS starting with Windows Vista. It's XAudio 'down-level' that requires mixing the modern Windows 8.x SDK and the legacy DirectX SDK,  plus having to use the legacy DirectX SDK REDIST (DirectSetup).

The root reason you are getting a 'runtime' error instead of a 'compile-time' error is that you didn't set _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0601 for Windows 7 (or 0x0600 for Windows Vista). If you had, the XINPUT.H header in the Windows 8.x SDK would automatically use the XInput 9.1.0 version and the XAUIOD2.H header in the Windows 8.x SDK would have errored out and told you it wasn't going to work for Windows 7.

Finally, I've cleaned up and reposted many of the old Direct SDK samples to [MSDN Code Gallery](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/) in such a way that they don't need the legacy DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is, if you develop XAudio2 program on Win 8, use the Windows SDK, otherwise, use DirectX SDK.

If you are working on Win7, make sure

1. the head file XAudio2.h you are using comes from the DirectX SDK, that's something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\XAudio2.h, not come from the Win8 SDK, something like C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\XAudio2.h(in case you installed the Win8 SDK)
2. Call CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); before calling XAudio2Create, since the old version(before 2.8) of XAaudio2 was created by COM, so it does not need a .lib file, and there is no .lib file for XAudio2 before Win8.

This page below contains a detail introduction of the version of XAudio2, you can take a look.

[XAudio2 Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So...you cant develop code that works between win 7 and win 8 using XAudio2?? Im confused...will app using XAudio2 from june 2010 SDK work on win 8?

Comment: I think, it is possible to use Direct X SDK on windows 8 to development XAudio 2 apps.